# How to containerize system with files- to install apps in seperate space, so that app is not in system and removing container the apps would be gone?

Tags: command-line, virtualization, application-development, container, snapshot

How to containerize system with files- to install apps in seperate space, so that app is not in system and removing container the apps would be gone?

Snapshots or clones of system and then working in them or reverting to previous state?

Want to use some container and option to move it to other computers. Optionally to freeze state.

Was there something native for Ubuntu?

I want to use 5 apps for one week, then not to reinstall all then how to get rid of apps without uninstalling something that might get left behid?

Is there something else without docker or kubernetes or they are not for saving filesystem differences and files in them with specific versions of apps i install with apt?

For example, i want to try docker and then remove it and all files i used with it. So how to install docker in seperate container where i play with docker and later move container to another computer or remove container that contains docker containers thingies.

Comment: You hinted to a tool that can serve this purpose: docker. There are actually different container engines. A tool like Podman allows to manage these.